# Checkbox List not being populated after formatting array as JSON and mapping in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

plunk - https://plnkr.co/edit/2ptIAdOyaIw8mGqpU7Cp?p=preview

Rundown of what's happening - `onload` executing function `createObjectFromEntityArrayWithKeys()`, which formats array of values to add two new keys, one of which belonging to a new value boolean `checked`.  New array, `$scope.newEntityArray` , is created on the `$scope` and accessed in my `ng-repeat`.  It is assigned new formatted data.

This stems from an earlier problem - saving the state of an `ng-repeat` checkbox menu while/after it is/has been filtered.

Because I'm working with an array of only values, I had to alter this to attach a boolean, `checked`, to each value - leaving me with an array of JSON objects.  This enables me to save the state of each checkbox.  Problem is I think my mapping is incorrect, or my usage of ng-repeat with object mapping is.  I'm really not sure why the list is not being populated. Any help appreciated.

EDIT

I've also tried using two `ng-repeats`, but same result:

```
<div ng-repeat="entity in newEntityArray | filter:simpleFilter">
    <div ng-repeat="(val, checked) in entity">
        <label> <input
           style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px"
           type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"
           ng-change="setModalEntity(val,checked)" /> <a>{{val}}</a>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused exactly by the use of this `onload` calling a function from the global scope. You should refactor in a "angular way" trying something like this:

Controller:

```
var createObjectFromEntityArrayWithKeys = function(){
  $scope.newEntityArray = entityArray.map(function(value){
      return {"val":value, "checked":false};
  });
};

// execute when load the controller
createObjectFromEntityArrayWithKeys();
```

View:

I only removed the `onload` attribute.

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller = "mainCtrl">
    <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="simpleFilter">
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="entity in newEntityArray | filter:simpleFilter">
      <label> <input
        style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 5px"
        type="checkbox" ng-model="entity.checked"
        ng-change="setModalEntity(entity.val,entity.checked)" /> <a>{{entity.val}}</a>
      </label>
    </div>
    {{entityFromSelection}}
  </div>
</body>
```

[DEMO PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/pFxSlmiE11LAlwuwJutf?p=preview)